# PostgreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu Lucid fails to start - how to debug?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-10.04, chef-solo, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant with Chef Solo to setup a Lucid 64 box.

I'm using a Chef recipe to install PostgreSQL 9.1 from Martin Pitt's backports.

The install goes ok until the point where the database is started with

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

There's a log pause and the command fails.

If I run pg_ctl manually, the database starts!

The entire contents of my postgresql-9.1-main log file is:

```
2012-05-07 11:01:18 PDT LOG:  database system was shut down at 2012-05-07 11:01:16 PDT
2012-05-07 11:01:18 PDT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2012-05-07 11:01:18 PDT LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2012-05-07 11:01:18 PDT LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2012-05-07 11:01:26 PDT LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2012-05-07 11:01:26 PDT LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2012-05-07 11:01:26 PDT LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2012-05-07 11:01:26 PDT LOG:  shutting down
2012-05-07 11:01:26 PDT LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I've tried to change the postgresql config file to get more info into the logfile, but that hasn't worked at all.

How do I debug this to find out what is failing so I can fix it?

Comment: Without any hint from the log files it will be just about guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Some things I would start with:

- ensure that postgresql is not already running
- check permisssions on `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main`

However I would advise starting postgresql using `pg_ctlcluster`. This script is called by the init script, and is a wrapper for `pg_ctl` which among other things performs several sanity checks. If those checks were to fail, they would prevent postgresql from starting.

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.1 main start
```